# What is the value of this loop counter

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Came across this question but unable to solve. What will be the value of the variable "counter"

int counter = 0;
for (int loop_1=0; loop_1 < 10; loop_1++) {
for (int loop_2=loop_1 + 1; loop_2 < 10; loop_2++) {
for (int loop_3=loop_2 + 1; loop_3 < 10; loop_3++) {
for (int loop_4=loop_3 + 1; loop_4 < 10; loop_4++) {
for (int loop_5=loop_4 + 1; loop_5 < 10; loop_5++) {
    counter++;
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: Hint: What if you made each counter count to $2$, find the result, then $3$ instead of $10$? Can you discover the pattern? Can you then do it analytically and see what would happen? Regards

Comment: ... or just compile and run :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Each time `counter++` is executed, `loop_1` up to `loop_5` make up a different subset (in ascending order) of $\{0,\ldots,9\}$.

Answer (score 0):

10C5 ; 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  it is equal to find no of increasing seq of size 5 in previous series. which is 10C5 because 10C5 means combination of 5 object in 10 distinct object and in every combination of 5 object there is only one increasing sequance.